# KDTree with masked arrays

Tags: python, scipy, similarity, kdtree

Given a sample masked array and a query on a KDTree,

```
In [6]: data = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))*1.0

In [7]: madata = np.ma.array(data)

In [9]: madata[1,1] = ma.masked

In [10]: madata
Out[10]:
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 1.0 2.0]
 [3.0 -- 5.0]
 [6.0 7.0 8.0]],
         mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]],
   fill_value = 1e+20)

In [11]: from scipy.spatial import KDTree

In [12]: matree = KDTree(madata)

In [13]: matree.query([3,0,5])
Out[13]: (4.0, 1)
```

Is this valid to query the tree using a non-masked array? or a masked-array should be used since the tree is constructed using masked arrays.

Another question, is this a reasonable approach to find most similar data pairs, something similar to finding most similar strings yet for numerical values? My original dataset is about 50k by 20, which contains many missing values. So use of masked arrays and a fast implementation is desired.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't count on the KDTree doing anything special with the masking.  My guess is that it uses the underlying data array as is.

A masked array has a `data` attribute and `mask` attribute.  The `np.ma` functions and methods pay attention to both.  But for many tasks they `fill` their data with a suitable value, and then do regular `numpy` actions.  For example if summing rows or columns it will replace the masked elements with 0s; if taking a product, with 1s.

Study the KDTree documentation.  If they say something about using masked arrays, then follow those instructions.  But if you don't find anything, it probably ignores the mask.

---

Look at the `KDTree` code.  It's `init` starts with:

```
def __init__(self, data, leafsize=10):
    self.data = np.asarray(data)
    ....
```

Look at `np.asarray(madata)`.  The result is the underlying `data`; not a masked array anymore.  So masking the array makes no difference.

---

See what happens when there's a Nan in the data:

```
In [256]: tree.data
Out[256]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,  nan,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.]])

In [257]: tree.query([3,4,5])
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\kdtree.py:314: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in maximum
  side_distances = np.maximum(0,np.maximum(x-self.maxes,self.mins-x))
Out[257]: (5.196152422706632, 0)
```

The default setting is to display a warning like this the first time it is encountered in a session (or context).

```
In [265]: np.maximum([1,2,0,np.nan],[3,2,0,0])
-c:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in maximum
Out[265]: array([  3.,   2.,   0.,  nan])

In [266]: np.maximum([1,2,0,np.nan],[3,2,0,0])
Out[266]: array([  3.,   2.,   0.,  nan])
```

You are welcome to study the `KDTree` code, but it looks like it just lets the normal `numpy` handling of nans to occur.  It does nothing special.

Can you omit the NaN points?

The masked-array compressed might not be what you want, since it returns a flattened version of the array:

```
In [268]: madata.compressed()
Out[268]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.])
```

Or fill with something useful?

```
In [271]: madata.filled(999)
Out[271]: 
array([[   0.,    1.,    2.],
       [   3.,  999.,    5.],
       [   6.,    7.,    8.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How about if there are NANs in the data? Could KDTree handle these situations correctly? NANs are the main reason that I intented to use masked arrays.

Comment: So there is no problem constructing the tree, yet query seems meaningless when there is NaN in the data. This is the main issue. If I fill data with some other numbers, isn't this going to bias the result?